# Customize delay emails in outlook?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2013, email-filter

How can I delay my sent mail for a few minuets when its sent to multiple address but the exempted emails (like my coworkers) should be sent right away so they can notify me, lets say if there's a mistake before its to late?

So this is my question when using outlook rules I can or delay all emails but when I exempt some emails from the rules the email gets sent right away even its sent to additional mail address.

Could anyone provide a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you want with Outlook rules.

I think the better solution is, thoroughly check the email first or send it to someone else first before sending it out!

If you're really desperate for this to work, you *may* be able to do this using VBa, you can use the [Application_ItemSend()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865076%28v=office.15%29.aspx) function to read through all recipients, decide who to send to or not, put in timers(sleeps) but it will be fiddly.